# Libgdx + rotate sprite point to the touch position

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm having problem trying to point my "arrow_sprite" to the touch position.

The result I want is that the arrow(the sprite that I want to rotate)will point to the touch position.

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to calculate the vector between the touch position and the sprite position. To do so you have to unproject the touch position received through your InputProcessor.

```
public class MyInputProcessor implements InputProcessor {
   ...

   @Override
   public boolean touchDown (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
      Vector3 touchDown = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
      camera.unproject(touchDown);
      Vector3 spritePosition = new Vector3(yourSpriteX, yourSpriteY, 0);
      spritePosition.sub(touchDown);
      return false;
   }

   ...
}
```

Now we have a vector pointing from your sprite to the touch position. From there you just need to calculate the rotation angle. One way would be to use Vector2.angle(), as such creating a Vector2 from the spritePosition Vector3.

Comment: Thank you Bach. I had an idea of creating a vector (actually, i created a vector2) but won't work because I have no idea about the camera projection. i'll try your solution. Appreciated your help.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to draw in 2D, then you have to set your SpriteBatch to Camera.combined,

something like this : yourBatch.setProjectionMatrix(yourCamera.combined);

Then you must unproject the camera like "batch" said.

After, you must choose if you want to use a vector or 2d coordinate. Basically identycal ending for angle calculation :

First define a float degrees then make it like so in the touchDown method :

```
degrees = (float) ((Math.atan2 (touchPoint.x - arrowPosition.x, -(touchPoint.y - arrowPosition.y))*180.0d/Math.PI)+90.0f);
```

assuming you use a Vector3 or 2 for both input and arrow.

then when rendering the Arrow sprite :

```
Batch.draw(Arrow, x, y, originX, originY, width, height, scaleX, scaleY, degrees);
```

Hope this will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Psilopat said, we define the degree by :

```
degrees = (float) ((Math.atan2 (touchPoint.x - arrowPosition.x, -(touchPoint.y - arrowPosition.y))*180.0d/Math.PI)+90.0f);
```

but if the rotation seems wrong, change the "+90.0f" at the end of line to something else. My arrow is pointing up, so I change it to "-180.0f"